# Trying to train a tensorflow model, but get: ImportError: cannot import name 'tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.framework'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have been trying train a pre trained model for a few days now, I am using:

ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8

I have downloaded the models complied and the protos etc... I can get the object detection run in my own script on my webcam.

But I can't get it to train.

I'm using an up to date Windows 10 machine:

Here is my tensorflow installs:

```
tensorboard                   2.10.1
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.10.1
tensorflow-addons             0.22.0
tensorflow-datasets           4.9.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.10.0
tensorflow-hub                0.16.1
tensorflow-intel              2.10.1
tensorflow-io                 0.31.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.31.0
tensorflow-metadata           1.13.0
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.7.5
tensorflow-text               2.10.0
termcolor                     2.4.0
terminado                     0.18.0
text-unidecode                1.3
tf-keras                      2.15.0
tf-models-official            2.10.1
tf-slim                       1.1.0
```

here is the code i am trying to run:

````
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection import model_main

def main():
    # Set the paths to your pipeline configuration and model directory
    pipeline_config_path = r"C:\python\models\ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8\pipeline.config"
    model_dir = r"C:\python\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py"  # Replace with your desired directory

    # Run the training process
    tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO)
    model_main.tf_main(pipeline_config_path, model_dir)```


and this is the error i am getting:


ImportError: cannot import name 'tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.framework' (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\__init__.py)

i am very stuck and i have been trying for a few days to fix this, i have tried 



import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/clone/repo/models/research/slim")
from nets.inception_v4 import *

Does anyone have any help to offer in resolving the import issue?
````

Comment: What happens when you run `python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=[PATH_TO_MODEL_DIR] --pipeline_config_path=[PATH_TO_PIPELINE_CONFIG]
` direct from the command line?

Comment: i get the same error:
```ImportError: cannot import name 'tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.framework' (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\__init__.py)```

Comment: Please have you found a way around?